# Properties of the union of two connected graphs, if their intersection is not connected

Tags: algorithm, graph

Let `G1=(V, E1)and G2=(V, E2)` be connected graphs on the same vertex set V
with more than two vertices. If `G1∩G2=(V, E1∩E2)` is not a connected graph, then the graph `G1∪G2=(V, E1∪E2)`

a)cannot have a cut vertex.

b)must have a cycle

c)must have a cut-edge (bridge)

d) Has chromatic number strictly greater than those of G1 and G2

=========================================================================

> Correct answer is the option (b)

=========================================================================

My Approach is:
[image]

The thing is I'm getting option a) also correct the way I choose the graph. So, How I would be sure in Exam what Graph to take so I get a correct answer as you can see here right answer is option b), but I'm also getting a) correct.

Comment: "... what Graph to take ...": a single example can only be used to disprove something (conter-example). To prove something that should hold for all graphs you need another approach.

Comment: Does the question specify whether the edges are directed? That's important.

Comment: As an exam technique, since it's usually easy to find counterexamples when you're trying to - for a multiple choice like this, if you can assume that one answer is correct then it may be easier to find counterexamples for all but one option in a multiple choice and assume the remaining to be true than to actually prove any of them.

Comment: @Henry what approach would that be?

Comment: @moreON No, edges are not directed. It's an undirected Graph!

Comment: In this case you could argue with the number of edges. You know G1 and G2 are connected, so must have at least a certain number of edges (how many?). G1 intersected with G2 is not connected, this tells you that G1 and G2 must not have exactly the same edges. Now, G1 union G2 must have more edges than each graph alone, which gives ... (consider how many edges a graph can have without containing a cycle).

Comment: @Henry Yes, makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If your goal was to disprove by counter-example, then you got off to a good start with a simple graph with 3 vertices.

[image]

Such a graph meets the requirements that G1 and G2 are connected, and the intersection is not connected. However, the union only disproves answer c). Specifically, the union

- does not have a cut vertex, so a) is ***allowed***
- does have a cycle, so b) is ***allowed***
- does not have a cut-edge, so c) is ***eliminated***
- has chromatic number 3, whereas G1 and G2 have chromatic number 2, so d) is ***allowed***

The next step is to realize that d) is almost certainly wrong. The reason: it's easy to add nodes to a graph without changing its chromatic number. Which is to say that it should be easy to find an example where G1 and G2 are three colored, and the union is also three colored.

So that leaves you with a) or b).
If you guess that a) is wrong, then you need to find a graph that has a cut vertex, and has a cycle.
If you guess that b) is wrong, then you need to find a graph that does **not** have a cut vertex, and does **not** have a cycle.

Guessing that b) is wrong is a little problematic, because a graph with no cycles is a [tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory)) or a [path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_graph), and trees and paths are full of cut vertices.

So the next step is imagine a graph that has a cut vertex. The first such graph that came to me is the hourglass:

[image]

Once again, G1 and G2 are connected, and the intersection is not connected. This time, the union disproves three of the answers. Specifically, the union

- does have a cut vertex, so a) is ***eliminated***
- does have a cycle, so b) is ***allowed***
- does not have a cut-edge, so c) is ***eliminated***
- has chromatic number 3, and G1 and G2 also have chromatic number 3, so d) is ***eliminated***

Note that we haven't proven b) is correct, only that a) c) and d) are definitely incorrect, so b) is the answer by elimination.

Answer (score 1):

To actually prove that G1 ∪ G2 contains a cycle.

There are two cases to consider, first the trivial case:

If either G1 or G2 contain a cycle, then G1 ∪ G2 must have a cycle - the cycle that existed in G1 or G2.

The more interesting case is when both G1 and G2 are acyclic.

Some (hopefully) already established facts about any connected acyclic undirected graph G = (V,E) :

- There is exactly 1 path between every pair of vertices (V1 ∈ V, V2 ∈ V), V1 ≠ V2.
- |E| = |V| - 1.

So for G1 and G2 both being acyclic and connected, they both contain |V| - 1 edges.
Because G1 ∩ G2 is not connected, they must not be G1 = G2, there must be an edge that exists in G2 that does not exist in G1.

Consider this edge Ek = (Vi, Vj) such that (Vi, Vj) ∉ E1 and (Vi, Vj) ∈ E2

The graph G1 ∪ G2 contains the path from Vi to Vj that is in G1 because it contains all of the edges in G1. Because G1 does not already contain Ek, including it (from G2) creates a cycle including the path from Vi to Vj in G1, and the edge Ek, therefore G1 ∪ G2 must contain a cycle.